# Swift: which the equivalent of sscanf()?

Tags: ios, string, swift

In my iOS app I have team names saved as

```
very_complex name (number playes)
```

and to get the full name of the team I would need to read/split that string according to this format

`%s (%s)`

like we are used to doing with ``sscanf()`in C. How do we do that in Swift?

Comment: can you give us some examples?

Comment: For example, if I have a string `"my team name (2 players)"` I would like to read string according to the format `%s (%s)`, or better `%s (%d %s)` to get the 3 variables...

Comment: and for those of us who don't use sscanf() in C ...
are the three variables 'my team name', 2, 'players'?

Comment: yes, sorry...I mean right those

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no in-place replacement for sscanf() but the way to do it is to use class Scanner ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner) and by [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128792/nsscanner-tutorial-for-os-x)).

For your case:

```
let str = "My Team Name (2 players)" // %s (%d %s)
let scanner = Scanner(string: str)
var firstStrVal: NSString?
var dummyStrVal: NSString?
var intVal: Int = 0
var secondStrVal: NSString?

scanner.scanUpTo(" (", into: &firstStrVal)
scanner.scanCharacters(from: CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: "("), into: &dummyStrVal)
scanner.scanInt(&intVal)
scanner.scanUpTo(")", into: &secondStrVal)

print(str)
print(firstStrVal!)
print(intVal)
print(secondStrVal!)
print("\(firstStrVal!) (\(intVal) \(secondStrVal!))")
```

Result:

```
My Team Name (2 players)
My Team Name
2
players
My Team Name (2 players)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. You could use nil instead of dummyStrVal.

Answer (score 3):

** updated to current format, as suggested by `Nicholas Allio` **

I'm sure someone will come along with a regex solution - but until then, you can always parse strings with `componentsSeparatedByString`

```
let str = "very_complex name (42 players)"
var splitString1 = str.components(separatedBy: " (")
var splitString2 = splitString1[1].components(separatedBy: " ")

let teamName = splitString2[0]
let numberOfPlayers = Int(splitString2[0])
```

Comment: You have to import `Foundation` in order to use that method. Of course, in Swift 3 the method name changed in `components(separatedBy: CharacterSet)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approximate equivalent for sscanf, this depends on the Swift OCL libraries from github.com/eclipse/agileuml (in libraries*.zip):

```
static func scan(s : String, fmt : String) -> [String]
{ var result : [String] = []

  var ind : Int = 0 // s upto ind has been consumed
  let slen : Int = s.count

  var i : Int = 0
  while i < fmt.count  
  { let c : String = Ocl.at(str: fmt, ind: i+1) 
    if c == "%" && i < fmt.count - 1  
    { let d : String = Ocl.at(str: fmt, ind: i+2) 
      if d == "s"  
      { var schars : String = ""
        for j in ind...slen  
        { let z : String = Ocl.at(str: s, ind: j+1) 
          if Ocl.iswhitespace(s: z) 
          { break }
          else 
          { schars = schars + z }
        }
        result.append(schars)
        ind = ind + schars.count
        i = i + 1  
      }
      else if d == "d"
      { var ichars : String = ""
        for j in ind...slen  
        { let z : String = Ocl.at(str: s, ind: j+1) 
          if Ocl.isMatch(str: z, pattern: "[0-9]") 
          { ichars = ichars + z }
          else 
          { break }
        }
        result.append(ichars)
        ind = ind + ichars.count
        i = i + 1  
      }
      else if d == "f"
      { var fchars : String = ""
        for j in ind...slen  
        { let z : String = Ocl.at(str: s, ind: j+1) 
          if Ocl.isMatch(str: z, pattern: "[0-9.]") 
          { fchars = fchars + z }
          else 
          { break }
        }
        result.append(fchars)
        ind = ind + fchars.count
        i = i + 1  
      }
    }
    else 
    { if Ocl.at(str: s, ind: ind+1) == c   
      { ind = ind+1 }  
      else 
      { return result }
    }
    i = i + 1
  }
  return result 
}
```

This used like this: print(scan(s: "100#20.5/10", fmt: "%d#%f/%d"))